# Входящие подключения на l2tp

Tags: linux, сеть, udp, l2tp, connection

Не могу подключиться к второму адресу по l2tp. udp echo попробовал - идет только с одного интернета.

Отвечает с не тем сорс адресом.

iptables -t mangle

```
-A PREROUTING -i enp0s10 -j CONNMARK --set-xmark 0x64/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -i enp0s18 -j CONNMARK --set-xmark 0x65/0xffffffff
-A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
```

ip ru l

```
0:  from all lookup local 
219:    from all fwmark 0x64 lookup 100 
32762:  from 81.хх.хх.12 lookup 100 
32764:  from all fwmark 0x65 lookup 101 
32765:  from 109.yy.yy.13 lookup 101 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

ip ro l table 100

```
default via 81.хх.хх.1 dev enp0s10
```

ip ro l table 101

```
default via 109.yy.yy.1 dev enp0s18
```

ip r l

```
default via 81.хх.хх.1 dev enp0s10 metric 20 
default via 109.yy.yy.1 dev enp0s18 metric 21 onlink 
81.xx.xx.0/24 dev enp0s10 proto kernel scope link src 81.хх.хх.12
109.yy.yy.0/24 dev enp0s18 proto kernel scope link src 109.yy.yy.13
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1
```

Что забыл?

Добавил, пока не помогло

```
ip r a 81.хх.хх.0/24 dev enp0s10 proto kernel scope link src 81.хх.хх.12 table 100
ip r a 109.yy.yy.0/24 dev enp0s18 proto kernel scope link src 109.yy.yy.13 table 101
```

В контраке метка ставится

```
conntrack -L | grep mark=101 | grep 213.87.138.134
conntrack v1.4.4 (conntrack-tools): 1064 flow entries have been shown.
udp      17 178 src=213.87.138.134 dst=109.yy.yy.13 sport=44009 dport=1701 src=109.yy.yy.13 dst=213.87.138.134 sport=1701 dport=44009 [ASSURED] mark=101 use=1
```

не помогло

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp0s18 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

не помогло

```
sysctl net.ipv4.fwmark_reflect=1
```

Проблема в том что сетевой стек по udp берет исходящий адрес ответа из кеша маршрутизации, а не из контрака.

Answer (score 0):

Получил ответ UDP с нужного сорса занатив его на ненужный:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i enp0s18 -p udp --dport 1235 -j DNAT --to-destination 81.хх.хх.12
```